# google apps map get geocode from address in sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Not sure why this stopped working. I'm trying to get the latitude & longitude from an address. Was working at one point. Not sure what happened. I'm listing the address in column U.

```
function geocode(){
    var tkhCopy = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxx').getSheetByName('tkhCopy');
    var range = tkhCopy.getRange('U2:U');
    var addresses = range.getValues();

    // Determine the first row and column to geocode
    var row = range.getRow();
    var column = range.getColumn();

    // Set default destination columns
    var destination = new Array();
    destination[0] = 22; // column + 1;
    destination[1] = 23; // column + 2;

    // tkhCopy.insertColumnsAfter(column, 2);
    var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder();
    var count = range.getHeight();

    // Iterate through addresses and geocode
    for(i in addresses) {
        var location = geocoder.geocode(
            addresses[i]).results[0].geometry.location);
        tkhCopy.getRange(row, destination[0]).setValue(location.lat);
        tkhCopy.getRange(row++, destination[1]).setValue(location.lng);
        Utilities.sleep(200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have [hit a quota on the number of times you can use the Geocoder service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits). Wait a day and try again.